# Change wordpress theme via javascript click event

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Hi is it possible that on clicking a button on the website, a different theme can be set?  My client needs a polish translation of every page and wants the translation to be done manually, rather than by a plugin.  So I figure the easiest thing to do is to have a whole new theme with different text in header.php etc and footer and call a different menu in header.php which the polish navigation elements in instead.

Comment: Look at WPML.  It is "manual" using translation files/tables.  I've used it on a few international websites and it works great.

Comment: thanks but that's $79, I want to do it myself

Comment: It is VERY VERY VERY worth it.  You will save yourself a boat load of time.  How much time will it take you to set up multiple themes, have the ability to translate content (i.e. have all your content in multiple languages) and make sure everything is working properly?  If your time is worth even $20/hr that's only 4 hours of time to buy WPML, and you can re-sue it on all your projects.  I still say it's worth it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple themes is not too difficult.  The following hooks allow the current theme to be overridden:

```
function wp_14125148_set_template($theme) {
    if(<user has a specific theme>) $theme = "<user specific theme name here>";
    return $theme;
}

function wp_14125148_set_stylesheet($theme) {
    if(<user has a specific theme>) $theme = "<user specific theme name here>";
    return $theme;
}

add_filter( 'template', 'wp_14125148_set_template' );
add_filter( 'stylesheet', 'wp_14125148_set_stylesheet' );
```

The tricky part is detecting what theme the user should be served.  The usual way of doing this is having a theme selector which stores a cookie with the theme selection and then reloads the current page.  The plugin with the above selector code should check for the cookie and use the specified theme - or do nothing if there is no cookie.

Here is the codex entry for using cookies with Wordpress: http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Cookies

Comment: Thank you.  What plugin uses this?

Comment: the difficulty I am having is knowing how to set the theme via front end interaction.  i.e. on the click of an anchor run a php function..., or would I just set the cookie, and reload the page?

Comment: I just did a cursory scan and there are lots of plugins but most are old and I would not trust them.  There is the wpmu switcher which looks nice but is paid.

Comment: Ok - yea, the second part would be code that gets the list of themes (pretty easy I believe since I've done that in a different plugin before), and then creates links which allow the user to select a theme.  The links need to provide a url parameter (?newtheme=mytheme) and then the plugin needs to check for that url parameter and update the user's cookie.  And then, of course, you need cookie logic in the plugin code that sets the theme and stylesheet.

Comment: Ok, how do I actually set the theme and the stylesheet?  What are the $template and $stylesheet parameters?  I would have thought it was just the theme name.

Comment: Yes, it is just the theme name.  So you could default a var to the default theme name, and then override it if there is a cookie with an alternate theme name stored in it and then return that value.  Do the same for both theme and style.

Comment: Just realised that this will change the theme for ALL of the website users.  So if someone clicks on the english flag, but someone in another country then clicks polish a milisecond later, all users requesting that page will see the polish version, because the theme is switched.  Am I right?  How can I get around this?

Comment: If you use the sample code - yes it will change the code for all users.  It is just there to demonstrate how to change the theme that is given on a pageload.  But that code coupled with the cookie logic that governs what value is returned by those function will be user specific.

Comment: yes it will but it will still change the database value for the current theme when the theme is changed

Comment: No, that isn't how it works.  Wordpress reads the current theme from the database and sets that value internally.  Then it processes the 'template' and 'stylesheet' filters (if they exist) and overrides the default value based on what they return.  So if they return a value based on a cookie for the user, then you will only be overriding the theme for the one user.  I did make a mistake though - the filter passes the default template.  I'm updating the entry to reflect that.

Comment: ahhhh I seeeeeeee.  I thought it was changing the theme in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use translation files to help you change the text rather than having multiple themes for each language.

Then use a variable to set the 'current language' and include the right file.

If you have a different theme entirely you'll have 2 themes to maintain then.

I'm not sure if you use jQuery but I use this and find it very useful:
http://recursive-design.com/projects/jquery-i18n/